# Is mod_rewrite rewrite rule match depending on position in substitution?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to echo current state of a URL being rewrited in .htaccess if query string contains DEBUG phrase:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} DEBUG
RewriteRule .+ echo.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&url=$0&query=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and my echo.php script echoes expected URL.

But strangely when I change order of parameters in substitution to:

```
RewriteRule .+ echo.php?url=$0&ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&query=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

echoed url is "echo.php" itself.
Is this expected behavior, and if so why?

Comment: You could try adding the `[B]` flag to escape the backreferences. This may be an issue with the URL being added unescaped. You can get the URL via the `REQUEST_URI` environment variable anyway, you don't need to pass it in. Same for `QUERY_STRING` and `REMOTE_ADDR`. In PHP they are in the `$_SERVER` array, such as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Also, if you do want to do it in this way, you need to add `ENV`, so `%{ENV:REMOTE_ADDR}` since it is those same environment variables you are accessing. But try the `[B]` flag to solve the problem mentioned in your question.

Comment: Adding `[B]` flag didn't help. Thanks for hints how to get URL in PHP script, but I was rather interested in getting answer how mod_rewrite works and why it acts that strange way, rather then how to echo the URL.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps You wrote: "You can get the URL via the REQUEST_URI environment variable anyway", but I can't get current state of URL in a middle of rewriting process if I have more than 1 rewrite rule, so I need to pass it the way I did it.

Comment: You can get insight on what's going on by adding `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` to your main config and then checking the error log (or another number between 1 and 8 for less or more info). To get the last rewritten URL in PHP use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.

Answer (score 0):

When I test, I don't get the different behaviour you are stating. When I use the rule either way round, I get `echo.php` as the URL, when visiting `example?DEBUG`. And this is because rules in `.htaccess` will keep looping (because the whole directory processing starts again after the rewrite, including the rewrite rules) until the URL does not change. So since you are matching `.+` you will always end up with `echo.php` unless some prior rule gets in the way and ends processing of that iteration before reaching your rule.

You can prove this to yourself by adding the `[END]` flag to the rule which stops any further mod_rewrite processing, and then you will get the behaviour you are expecting. The difference you are seeing must be due to your prior rules in some way.

As mentioned in the comments, a better way to debug mod_rewrite is to make use of the `LogLevel rewrite:traceX` option, with `X` being a number between 1 and 8. 3 is a good place to start, and increase from there if not enough info. There is a **lot** of info as you increase towards 8. You can only enable it in the main config. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). Make sure to switch it off again as all that logging affects performance. It does not interfere with any earlier `LogLevel` directives.